# Optimistic concurrency features in Azure Mobile

Tags: c#, azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services

I have a question regrading data synchronization in azure mobile services , in this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/12/02/accessing-optimistic-concurrency-features-in-azure-mobile-services-client-sdks.aspx

it's mentions azure uses 2 parameters for this _version and _updatedAt. say I have 2 client one web and one mobile . I have mobile client get data from server with version 1, and the client goes off line . My web client updates the data now it's version at 2 . my mobile client goes back on line tries to push it changes but it version is behind so the changes are reject . what is the use case for  _updatedAt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version column is all that is used by the OC feature, and drives the use of if-match headers.

UpdatedAt is used as part of an incremental sync process for creating a local cache of data.  So when you try to pull new changes down to your local cache, the client will only ask for records who's updatedAt is newer than the last time it ran.